# Add placeholder DataGrid item after ComboBox selection

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a WPF DataGrid with a possibility of add new rows (`CanUserAddRows="True"`). One of my columns is a ComboBox. With the following code I can bind data to this ComboBox:

```xml
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Validator" MinWidth="150">
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ValidatorVariables, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedValidatorVariable, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      IsEnabled="{Binding HasValidator, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

If I select a ComboBox item first in a placeholder row, then new item won't be created from this placeholder row. Placeholder row will be added to the item source only if I enter edit mode in a Text column. CheckBox column does not work either, only Text column.

This causes a sideffect:

1. select ComboBox item
2. enter edit mode in a Text column

Result: previously selected ComboBox item is cleared

Is there any solution for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any input control, such as for example a `ComboBox`, is supposed to be put in the Cell**Editing**Template. The `CellTemplate` should contain a `TextBlock` that displays the currently selected value:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Validator" MinWidth="150">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedValidatorVariable}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ... />
        </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks it seems fine. But what about a CheckBox column? First I check a CheckBox in a cell then move to the next ComboBox column, and after it is in edit mode, the previous CheckBox is getting unchecked. I can evade this if I put TextBlock in the CellTemplate and CheckBox in the CellEditTemplate. Should I use some disabled CheckBox in the CellTemplate and enabled CheckBox in the CellEditTemplate? It seems weird to click twice into the cell to get editable CheckBox instead of a one click which checks the CheckBox instantly.